# Search the object with like in "Find database objects" on snowflake.com

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to search the object with like instead of just starting with.

"Find database objects" currently allow only the object search with Starting name as **name%**.

is there a way to make it a **%name%** ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is about UI's search option. Unfortunately it only supports searching with starting name. On the other hand, you can use SHOW OBJECTS command to search everything in your account:

```
SHOW OBJECTS LIKE '%ATI%' IN ACCOUNT;
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-objects.html